# What is the term for a noun or phrase that is used in place of a longer list of nouns?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, linguistics

For example, I could refer to 'the big five', instead of listing the five animals considered dangerous to hunt. I've replaced the list of animals with the noun phrase 'the big five'.

I know this could be a form of substitution but it's a clearly recognisable phrase with specific meaning.

Comment: 'Genus' in its less specialised sense is correct, but there would be confusion if used for the _big five_. Trivially, a _set_ is a collection of different entities with some overarching connection (here, dangerous African ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called a "*designation*".

> (SOED) **designation** **7** A descriptive name, an appellation;

- From now on the five dangerous animals will be referred to [by the designation/as] "the big five".

Answer (score 0):

**label** (n.)

> A classifying phrase or name applied to a person or thing, especially
> one that is inaccurate or restrictive. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/label)

> A word or phrase that describes or identifies something or someone
> [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/label)